# "during one of my girlfriend's games"

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, syntactic-analysis

I was trying to say "During one of my girlfriend's soccer games..."

The problem is when I spoke it, it could be interpreted as

> "Out of all of my girlfriends... during one of their games this happened"

-or-

> "Out of all of the games that my girlfriend has played in... during one of those games this happened"

I have only one girlfriend, so how can I word this sentence so that when I speak it, it can only be interpreted as "during my one of my (singular possessive) girlfriend's games..."

Thanks! God bless!

Comment: "This is my girlfriend.  During one of her soccer games...."

Comment: Seriously, given that most people have only one girlfriend at a time, the odds of your original statement being misinterpreted are vanishingly low.

Comment: Plural girlfriends might be serial, not simultaneous. How about "During one of the games my girlfriend played in..."?

Comment: During a game of football in which my girlfriend was playing ...

Comment: Dare I say it? You could use her name. She might even like that. (Said half in jest, and half in fear)

Comment: @WayneJohnston the person I was talking to has never met my girlfriend, so they wouldn't know her name. However, that is the best approach :)

Comment: Please stop rolling back to poor revisions. "Thanks" and such are extraneous and will be removed. This is not a forum.

Comment: @simchona I would like to thank people for their efforts. Why on earth would a website make it against the rues to thank users for their efforts.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw It is considered **spam**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @simchona I read through that and I don't think it is considered spam... the only valid point in that article is that the "hi" would take away more from the article preview. But a "thank you" at the bottom shouldn't have ANY negative impact what-so-ever.

Comment: Please stop adding "thanks". It is site policy to remove such taglines, and I will now lock this post to prevent you from adding it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* unambiguous rewording would be...

> *"During one of my **current** girlfriend's [soccer] games ..."*

...but if OP doesn't like the implication that he has multiple girlfriends *over time*, perhaps...

> *"During one of the [soccer] games my girlfriend played in..."*

Comment: The first *still* may imply multiple current girlfriends.

Comment: @T.E.D.: In spoken form, maybe you couldn't tell the difference, but *my* written version doesn't say **girlfriends' games**, so I'm in the clear (on paper and on screen! :)

Comment: The question currently reads "The problem is when I **spoke** it it could be interpreted as..."

Comment: I prefer "my current girlfriend". It keeps her on her toes. If you marry her, you should call her "my first wife".